# USB packet and data buffer capture

Tags: api, usb, capture, labview, sniffer

I need a software or application with API support to capture USB packet and data buffer. I would like to analyse the captured data using LabVIEW.

1. Suggest applications for usb packet and data capture with API support, so that I can access them using LabVIEW.

Or

2. Alternate methods to capture and analyse usb data using LabVIEW

I had tried a approach using logman.exe . But that doesn't log all the USB packets. Has anyone tried logman to capture the usb packets?

Comment: I think you need to supply more detail about what you are trying to do. Do you have a USB device and an existing driver, and you're trying to 'sniff' the communication between them? What kind of USB device is it?

Comment: Have you checked the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315597/what-software-usb-sniffers-are-available-for-windows?rq=1 ?

Comment: Yes, i checked through all of them. But most of the open source applications doesn't serve my purpose and the paid ones are costly to purchase for my application. So apart from those mentioned in the other link, I wanted to know if there are any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can consider using VISA functions.
A few examples are shipped with Labview (open example finder and look for USB).

[Here is](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/4478/en/) a starting point giving instructions about how to give VISA access to the device.

Comment: According to my understanding, VISA helps to interact with the instrument (correct me if I'm wrong). But, I need to capture all the usb data packets from the pc to the instrument once the instrument communication is established.

Comment: VISA can be used also to capture all data coming from an interface. Give a look to the example "USB RAW - Interrupt.vi" shipped with Labview. This is basically a USB monitor.

Comment: I went through the example. Will the same procedure to capture data work, if multiple devices are connected to a hub and the hub is connected to the pc inturn?

Comment: FYI, I tried NI IO Trace tool, what happens there is similar to VISA approach rite?

Answer (score -1):

You need find out some windows dll's and use it in labview. the examples provided for NI USB devices.